# java language. it says my file doesn't exist but it does

Tags: java, file

```
private void traverse(String dir, int ctr) throws IOException

{
    // get current file and name                            

    File myFile = new File(dir);
    System.out.println("dir path: " + myFile.getAbsolutePath()); // correct path
    System.out.println("exists? : " + myFile.exists()); // returns false
    String name = myFile.getName();
    System.out.println(dir + " is dir? " + myFile.isDirectory());
    if (name.equals("tree.txt"))
        return;

    // print tabs and name
    for (int i = 0; i < ctr; ++i)
        bw2.write("\t");
    bw2.write(name);
    bw2.newLine();


    if (myFile.isFile() && name.charAt(0) != '.') 

    {
        File f = new File(dir + "." + name);
        int version = 1; // if doesn't exist then version is 1

        if (f.exists())
        {
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(f);
            InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(fis);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);

            version = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine()); // get version

            br.close();
        }

        fos1 = new FileOutputStream(f);

        osw1 = new OutputStreamWriter(fos1);

        bw1 = new BufferedWriter(osw1);

        bw1.write(version); // write version

        bw1.close();

    }

    else if (myFile.isDirectory()) 

    {
        String dirContents[] = myFile.list(); 

        for (String content : dirContents)

        {
            traverse(dir + content + '/', ctr + 1);
        }

    }
} // end traverse
```

output:

```
kedy@Laptop:~/Desktop/connection$ java Server
dir path: /home/kedy/Desktop/connection/test.txt
exists? : false
test.txt/ is dir? false
dir path: /home/kedy/Desktop/connection/tree.txt
exists? : false
tree.txt/ is dir? false
dir path: /home/kedy/Desktop/connection/folder 2
exists? : false
folder 2/ is dir? false
dir path: /home/kedy/Desktop/connection/test2.txt
exists? : false
test2.txt/ is dir? false
dir path: /home/kedy/Desktop/connection/folder
exists? : false
folder/ is dir? false
```

Comment: Could you show us the output when you execute it, there's a few println's in there.

Comment: it might seem messy cuz i don't know how to post code in these comment boxes

Comment: kedy@Laptop:~/Desktop/connection$ java Server
dir path: /home/kedy/Desktop/connection/tree.txt
tree.txt/ is dir? false
dir path: /home/kedy/Desktop/connection/folder 2
folder 2/ is dir? false
dir path: /home/kedy/Desktop/connection/test2.txt
test2.txt/ is dir? false
dir path: /home/kedy/Desktop/connection/folder
folder/ is dir? false

Comment: to make it simpler cuz the output i posted is unreadable. all files and directories had the correct path, returned false for exists() and return false for isDirectory()

Comment: Just add a section to your question with the output.

Comment: @Troggy haha good idea. i just did it

Comment: How come there's no "exists?" in the output?

Comment: hmm, i must've ran an earlier version or sth, tho the problem still exists. i have updated the output

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the output, I would venture a guess that there is indeed no file `"test.txt/"`. However, there probably is a file `"text.txt"`.

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
traverse(dir + content + '/', ctr + 1);
```

to

```
traverse(dir + '/' + content, ctr + 1);
```

Comment: this obviously is a mistake but this does not change the output because the program should never reach here since nothing seems to be a directory

Answer (score 0):

I will probably end up adding to this answer, but, first, you may want to check permissions, to see if the application has read access.

Which version of Java, which OS?

If you move the file to a common directory, common to all users, can the file be found?

You may want to have the path be an argument, so you can easily change it without recompiling your application, which testing this.

Comment: java jdk 1.6, ubuntu. i copy pasted most of this code from my client side's code (the client's side works). yes the application has read access.